# Stopping running unit tests, and get logging

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have some unit test that deadlocks for some reason. I want to stop the running unit test, and see the messages(t.Log). If I just do CTRL-C I don't get the messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can do CTRL-\ and it will give you a backtrace of where it's hung. I'm not sure if there's a clean way to get the log messages though.

Comment: It works for getting what test is running, but without the backtrace :-( Maybe you have a link or something where I might be able to find it, I have searched like a maniac, and haven't found any info(not even about the CTRL-\)

Comment: Perhaps it is Operating-System dependent, but if you send a go program the SIGQUIT signal (which on Linux and Mac, at least, is done with CTRL-\, maybe it's different on Windows) then it will abort and dump a full stack trace of every goroutine.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and when I do CTRL-\ it doesn't show stacktrace (other it started). I will try explicit SIGQUIT via kill when I come home. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `-v` flag with `go test`, e.g. `go test -v github.com/myname/package`

This will cause the any logging to be output as the tests are run.

Comment: I already do this, it still keeps the log back until it is finished(however it never finishes so I can't see it).